# How do you convert a Lead via the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, lead-conversion

Am a bit new to Salesforce, integrating with our existing systems which uses Python, so I'm making use of the [simple_salesforce module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce/0.65.1). It's working great, except I cannot figure out how you convert a Lead to a Contact/Account via the API. Is there some endpoint to do this?

Comment: The SOAP API supports this with convertLead(), the REST API does not as of V32. You'll need an Apex REST service as answered by A-d below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the answer in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663119/is-there-any-rest-service-available-in-saleforce-to-convert-leads-into-accounts)

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead/*')
global with sharing class RestLeadConvert {            

@HttpGet
global static String doGet() {
    String ret = 'fail';
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    String leadId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);              
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadId);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);           
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr ;
    try{
        lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        system.debug('*****lcr.isSuccess()'+lcr.isSuccess());            
        ret = 'ok';
    }
    catch(exception ex){
        system.debug('***NOT CONVERTED**');           
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

And use this as given in "Using Apex" section in the [simple_salesforce module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce/0.65.1) guide.

Comment: Thanks, looks like for some reason we don't have Apex available so I'll follow up with that, but I think this is the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that exposes all the features of the Apex LeadConvert functionality.

https://github.com/bolaurent/salesforce_rest_leadconvert