# how to convert lead to account using REST API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, soap

We are using Sales force REST API to handle our leads.Basically, [REST api](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php)

We want to convert lead to account using REST API. But it seems that it is not possible using REST API.

As I see here [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_ConvertLead_Sample_(Enterprise)) using SOAP it is possible but question is how can I do using REST API.

Comment: check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/50045/18731.. you need to create own rest resource and convert the lead to account

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ConvertLead/*')
global with sharing class RestLeadConvert {            

@HttpGet
global static String doGet() {
    String ret = 'fail';
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    String leadId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);              
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadId);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);           
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr ;
    try{
        lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        system.debug('*****lcr.isSuccess()'+lcr.isSuccess());            
        ret = 'ok';
    }
    catch(exception ex){
        system.debug('***NOT CONVERTED**');           
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

You can call above rest service using below url

```
<Your Instance URL>/services/apexrest/ConvertLead/<LeadId>
```