# Assistance with Salesforce Rest API for Converting Leads to Contacts

Tags: rest-api, contact, leads, lead-conversion

I am a newcomer to Salesforce and have been successfully utilizing Salesforce Rest APIs. However, I have encountered a challenge that is causing some difficulties for me. Specifically, I am having trouble with the process of converting a lead into a new contact, and it has become a bit of a headache.

I would like to inquire if there is an Rest API available to facilitate the conversion of a lead to a new contact. Your guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no standard REST API call for lead conversion.  You'll have to build your own endpoint, see [How do you convert a Lead via the REST API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50045/how-do-you-convert-a-lead-via-the-rest-api) for examples.